# Bandwidth of two-dimensional grid graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a subgraph of the two-dimensional grid and there are $n$ vertices in $G$. What is the maximum possible [graph bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth) of $G$ as a function of $n$?

If $G$ is a square grid graph with dimensions $k$ and $l$ (i.e., the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product_of_graphs) of two paths of length $k$ and $l$), it is known that $G$ has a bandwidth of $\min(k, l) \le \sqrt{kl} = \sqrt{n}$ [1]. Is there an $O(\sqrt{n})$ upper bound for grid graphs in general?

[1] Chvátalová, J., 1975. Optimal labelling of a product of two paths. Discrete Mathematics, 11(3), pp.249-253.

Comment: I have once seen the case above, and they (repliers) said that yes there is an O(n−−√). Sorry, I can not remember the source.